# jQueryで複数のイベント発生時処理を同時に定義する

Tags: jquery

```
$('.target').on('mousemove,touchmove', function(){ console.log('ok'); });
```

のようにカンマ区切りで複数のイベント発生時処理を同時に定義出来た気がするのですが、出来ませんでした。

```
$('.target').on('touchmove', function(){ console.log('ok'); });
$('.target').on('mousemove', function(){ console.log('ok'); });
```

または

```
func = function(){ console.log('ok'); };
$('.target').on('touchmove', func).on('mousemove', func);
```

のようにするしか方法はありませんか？
もう少しなエレガントな書き方はできないでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`events`はカンマではなくスペース区切りです。

```
$('.target').on('mousemove touchmove', function(){ console.log('ok'); });
```

Comment: ありがとうございましたm(_ _)m